# Figuring out angles and lengths of irregular quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

**Problem**

Given the triangle (sketched below) find $\angle B, \angle D$, the length of the diagonal $BD$ and the area of the quadrilateral.

Given values:

$\angle CAD = 40^o$

$\angle BAD = 90^o$

$CD = 5.0$

$AD = CD$

$AC = AB$

[image]

**My progress**

I found $\angle ACD = 40^o$ by the law of sines.

I found $\angle D = 100^0$ by the angle sum of a triangle, $\angle D = 180 - 2\cdot40$.

The rest remains a mystery to me. It seems like $\angle B$ should be solvable, but I can't see it.

Comment: You have $AC=AB$. So $\angle ABC=\angle ACB$.

Comment: @CYKwong - Ah, so they're both 65 degrees then?

Comment: Yes.The triangle is isosceles

Comment: Nice, thanks! Do you see a way to find BD? I can tell that $BD^2 = 5^2+AB^2$ since $ABD$ is a right triangle, but I can't seem to find an equation to supplement that with.

Comment: Find $AC$ first (cosine formula), which is equal to $AB$.

Comment: Ah yeah, I just now realized I can find AC using law of sines too, since everything else about ACD is known :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $AB=AC$ so $\angle ABC=\angle ACB$ and once $\angle BAC =50°$ then

$$2\angle ABC+50°=180° \to \angle ABC=65°$$

In order to find the area you just need to calculate $y$.

For that you can use cossine law at $\Delta ACD$:

$$AC^2=y^2=5^2+5^2-2\cdot5\cdot5\cdot \cos 100°\to y^2=25(1-2\cos 100°)$$

and the area will be:

$$(ABCD)=(ABC)+(ACD)=\frac{5\cdot 5\cdot \sin 100°}{2}+\frac{y\cdot y\cdot \sin 50°}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use law of sines in triangle ADC to get the value of y and evaluate the area of triangle ADC and ABC separately using the formula 1/2acsin(theta)

Comment: Area =34.78676353 units^2